# Wacom Intuos pen drawing while hovering?

Tags: stylus

Every time I open up SAI, I hover my pen over my tablet and it starts drawing without touching.

I've rebooted the tablet driver, removed any preferences, replaced the nib, and restarted my computer. I've restarted or removed anything I could. The only thing I could find was that I need to take the pen apart because something has moved, but the thread was for a different pen that's easier to get open than mine.

Anyone know how to fix this or do I need to get a new pen?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else is working the problem may just be outdated drivers. Check your wacom desktop center to see if there were any updates you missed. If you still have problems you may just need to replace your pen completely.